# Как отключить "Открыть с помощью" для определенного файла?

Tags: windows, реестр

Подскажите как отключить в контекстном меню "Открыть с помощью" для определенного файла, например для `.reg`

Для файлов `.bat` `.com` такое меню каким-то образом отключено, не могу найти параметр, который отвечает за отключение "Открыть с помощью" в контекстном меню.

В примере, код реестра который отключает "Открыть с помощью" для всех файлов, но необходимо отключить только для некоторых файлов.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Open With]
@="-{09799AFB-AD67-11d1-ABCD-00C04FC30936}"
```